# ambiguity between a string and a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, dynamic, deserialization, ambiguous

```
        string code = "ru";
        string searchUrl = $"{Endpoint}getLangs?key={ApiKey}&ui=en";
        string json;
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            json = client.DownloadString(searchUrl);
        }

        var dataObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
        return dataObject.langs.code;
```

In this snippet here `searchUrl` is a string and holds the URL of the API I am using. Now the last line `return dataObject.langs.code;` returns `null` as there is no such entry in the json which is in `dataObject`(a dynamic object). But `return dataObject.langs.ru;` returns a proper string that I was expecting.

This is happening because in `return dataObject.langs.code;` `code` is a dynamic member of `dataObject` and not the string code i declared above. How can I use that `code` that I declared and not the dynamic code it thinks there exists in `dataObject` since it is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `dynamic` at all. That's typically useful when you know the names you want to use at compile-time. I'd deserialize to a `JObject` and just use indexers, where you can provide the property name either using something you know at compile-time (like `"langs"`) or something you only know at execution time (like `code`):

```
var dataObject = JObject.Parse(json);
// Modify this to cast to whatever type you're actually interested in
return (string) dataObject["langs"][code];
```

Here's a complete example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        string code = "ru";
        JObject dataObject = JObject.Parse(json);
        string result = (string) dataObject["langs"][code];
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

With test.json containing:

```
{
  "langs": {
    "ru": "Russian",
    "en": "English",
    "fr": "French"
  },
  "misc": {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Russian
```

Comment: "That's typically useful when you know the names you want to use at compile-time." - don't you mean **don't know the names**?

Comment: @Enigmativity: Nope, I meant exactly what I wrote. Dynamic typing let's you write `dynamic d = ...; string result = d.Foo;` but that doesn't help you if you don't know the name "Foo" when you're writing the code. I know it sounds a bit odd given the term "dynamic", but that's the way it works.